# Where Do I Put a Template To Add Using {{block type="core/template" template="template.phtml"}}

Tags: template, cms

I am new to Magento and so sorry for the noddy question.

I am trying to add php to a CMS page and the way to do this appears to be to put the php (including Mage calls) to a phtml template and then add it to the CMS page with
`{{block type="core/template" template="template.phtml"}}`.

But, in all the examples that I can find saying that this is the way to do it none of them tell me where to put the phtml file so I can use the above.

So my question is; where do I put a template to call using
`{{block type="core/template" template="template.phtml"}}`?

Thanks in advance,
Norman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The template file is relative to your theme's template folder. But also taking into consideration the template fallback (see [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21333/layout-problems-with-extension-when-new-theme-installed/21336#21336) for more details) you have 2 options:

1. add the template file in your current theme:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/[CUSTOM_FOLDER]/[TEMPLATE].phtml
   ```
2. add the template file in the base package:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/[CUSTOM_FOLDER]/[TEMPLATE].phtml
   ```

Then, in your CMS page you will add `{{block type="core/template" template="[CUSTOM_FOLDER]/[TEMPLATE].phtml"}}`

Where `[YOUR_PACKAGE]` and `[YOUR_THEME]` are the currently used package and theme folders used on your store, and `[CUSTOM_FOLDER]` and `[TEMPLATE]` can be anything on your choice

Comment: alex.ayg and @Joshua43com - Thank you both for your replays. While working through what you have advised (even though I was sure I had tried this) I have realised that the reason that it was not working was that I had not clicked 'Hide Editor' before I had typed it. What you have advised has worked so thank you. Sorry for being such a fool. :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Magento SE.

An easy way to make this call from a static block is, add this to your static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/template.phtml"}}
```

Place page.phtml at this path, with your custom code:

```
app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/template/page/template.phtml
```

If you are still having problems, due to [Magento's hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777090/magento-fall-back-on-theme/25777391#25777391), you can also place it here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template.phtml
```

Be sure to flush your cache

Answer (score 0):

I try to do the same:

I created a file mycms.phtml in this folder:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cms
```

On the static page content/pages/mycmspage 
I added this line

```
{{block type="core/template" template="cms/mycms.phtml"}}
```

the testfile mycms.phtml only contains

```
<?php echo "test php"; ?>
```

This is not working for me?

also when placing the file here:

```
app/design/frontend/[myvendor]/[mytheme]/template/cms
```

My theme is a child theme of luma

is not working?

please advice

Comment: I use magento 2.3.1