# Override CMS page

Tags: cms, overrides

I have created a CMS page from backend. Now, I want to add phtml file for design of that CMS page.

Please help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CMS page add the following

```
{{block type="core/template" template="[FOLDER]/[FILENAME].phtml"}}
```

Where FOLDER is an existing or new folder in the template folder of either your custom theme or the base theme i.e.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/[FOLDER]/[FILENAME].phtml
```

See this answer for more information. [Where Do I Put a Template To Add Using {{block type="core/template" template="template.phtml"}}](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35749/where-do-i-put-a-template-to-add-using-block-type-core-template-template-te)

Comment: I am adding this code in local.xml         <block type="core/template" name="help-support" template="mycompany/cms/supoort.phtml" />   here name is my cms page url key. Now if I see on frontend php code of this file is display above the header. Sorry,But I think I am not understing your answer.Please help me

Comment: You said you created a CMS page in the backend and wanted to reference the template phtml from the CMS page. To do this you would edit this page and add the block type reference code from above, this will tell Magento to load the phtml template file when it loads the CMS page. Then create/edit your phtml to output whatever you want. If you are having trouble adding the CMS to the layout xml then that is another problem.